# Problem with Generics and sub-typing in my generic Tree implementation

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, tree, covariance

Consider this code:

```
public class TreeNode<T extends TreeNode<T, E>, E> {
    protected T parent;
    protected E data;
    protected List<T> children = new ArrayList<T>();

    public TreeNode(T parent, E data) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getRoot() {
        if (parent == null) {
            return this;       //<---- Problem is here!
        } else {
            return getParent().getRoot();

        }
    }

    public T getParent() {
        if (parent == null) {
           throw new RuntimeException("This already the parent!");
        } else {
            return parent;
        }
    }
}

/*
  incompatible types
    required: T
    found:    TreeNode<T,E>
*/
```

How can I fix that and make my code work?

Comment: Yes, it removed the need to cast before `getParent().getRoot()`. I wonder how to remove the last cast in `return (T) this;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the so-called [getThis() trick](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#What%20is%20the%20getThis%20trick?).  Declare a new method like so:

```
/** Subclasses must implement this method as {@code return this;} */
protected abstract T getThis();
```

Then when you need to use `this`, just call `getThis()` instead.  As a side note, implementing this method will confound a class like `BadNode` in @Michael Williamson's answer, thus making it harder to write such a class in the first place (which is a good thing).

Comment: Mhhh, I would prefer if subclasses wouldn't have to implement anything datastructure-related. That's more or less what I expected, implementing the type on a per-class base. But I would like to be able to use `TreeNode` without sub-classing it too.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do it without subclassing.  You could always just declare a simple `final class ConcreteTreeNode<E> extends TreeNode<ConcreteTreeNode,E>{}`

Answer (score 1):

It's not guaranteed that the type T is the same as the type of the class itself, so you need to add a cast to the line that doesn't compile:

```
public T getRoot() {
    if (parent == null) {
        return (T)this;
    } else {
        return getParent();
    }
}
```

To give a simple example of code that will expose the typing error:

```
public class GoodNode extends TreeNode<GoodNode, Integer> {
    public GoodNode(GoodNode parent, Integer data) {
        super(parent, data);
    }
}

public class BadNode extends TreeNode<GoodNode, Integer> {
    public BadNode(GoodNode parent, Integer data) {
        super(parent, data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GoodNode node = new BadNode(null, null).getRoot();
    }
}
```

Running BadNode.main causes a typing error since BadNode(null, null).getRoot() returns an object of class BadNode (since it has no parent), but because BadNode extends TreeNode<GoodNode, Integer>, the return type of getRoot() is GoodNode. Since BadNode cannot be cast to GoodNode, there's a class cast exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: BadNode cannot be cast to GoodNode
    at BadNode.main(BadNode.java:7)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that a few seconds ago. But I'm not sure if this is safe. Is there a chance that this will fail at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to be "too generic"?

```
public class TreeNode<E> {
    protected TreeNode<E> parent;
    protected E data;
    protected List<TreeNode<E>> children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<E>>();

    public TreeNode(T parent, E data) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public TreeNode<E> getRoot() {
        if (parent == null) {
            return this;       
        } else {
            return getParent(); // <--- ???
        }
    }
...
}
```

BTW: You might want to call something along the lines of parent.getRoot() instead of getParent().

Comment: The problem is that I want that sub-typing of `TreeNode` works. That's why the second generic type is there.

Comment: What you want is to sub-type the whole tree, not just some nodes? Then the page on the getThis() trick in @matt-mchenry's answer is likely to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a raw type in the extends clause? That might hinder type inference.
Try the following:

```
public class TreeNode<T extends TreeNode<T,E>, E> {
```